# ffmpeg installation on macOS for MoviePy fails with SSL error

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, moviepy, python-imageio

I'm trying to write a Python program that uses MoviePy on Mac OS 10.11.16 to convert an MP4 file to GIF. I use:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
```

and I get an error saying I need to call `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()` so I can download ffmpeg. I use:

```
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Imageio: 'ffmpeg.osx' was not found on your computer; downloading it now.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py", line 55, in download
    get_remote_file('ffmpeg/' + FNAME_PER_PLATFORM[plat])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/fetching.py", line 121, in get_remote_file
    _fetch_file(url, filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/fetching.py", line 177, in _fetch_file
    os.path.basename(file_name))
OSError: Unable to download 'ffmpeg.osx'. Perhaps there is a no internet connection? If there is, please report this problem.
```

I definitely have an internet connection. I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/624561/install-ffmpeg-on-os-x) link, and tried installing with Homebrew and Static builds, but neither have worked. It seems like compiling it myself would be a little too advanced for me (I've only briefly looked into it). I used `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()` on IDLE. I read something about using PyCharm to run the MoviePy code, but I get the same initial error. ffmpeg is currently in my `/usr/local/bin` folder. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank for your help.

Edit: I'm using Python 3.6.1

Comment: Try reporting it on imageio's GitHub issue tracker?

Comment: if my solution below was able to help you, I'd be happy if you could accept the solution as the answer

Answer (score 12):

#### I was able to find a workaround for macOS by debugging the fetching script:

1. manually download the built (this is where the SSL error occurs):
   https://github.com/imageio/imageio-binaries/raw/master/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-osx-v3.2.4
2. paste the file to the path: `/Users/yourusername/Library/Application\ Support/imageio/ffmpeg/`
3. re-run your code

#### what didn't solve my problem:

- upgrading moviepy with pip, then prompting the ffmpeg download through importing `movie.editor`
- explicitly importing imageio and executing `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()`
- `brew install ffmpeg`

Comment: For step 2, how does one paste the file to the path?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the late response. Unfortunately this does not work for me. I get the same errors as in my original post. However, I really appreciate that you took the time to try this out.

Comment: @MPath, use the command "mv source destination" in the terminal (type "Terminal" in spotlight to open a terminal)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this question using a solution similar to Bill Bell's. First, make sure that `ffmpeg` is actually installed on your system by running `brew install ffmpeg`. Then, running `which ffmpeg` should return something like `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`.

As Bill suggests, add `FFMPEG_BINARY = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"` before executing your python code or alternatively add:

```
import os    
os.environ["FFMPEG_BINARY"] = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg"
```

in your code. These worked on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I warn you, I know *nothing* about Mac OS. But here's a possibility.

Look in `config_defaults.py`, in the moviepy folder, which is where (on Linux and Windows) one can set the locations for certain executables.

Add the line

```
FFMPEG_BINARY = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg.osx"
```

to the bottom of the file, where I assume that `ffmpeg.osx` is the name of your FFMPEG executable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it to work with your approach. I appreciate your input though.