# error when running "imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()"

Tags: macos, python-2.7, ffmpeg, moviepy, python-imageio

I am trying to run the command `imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()` after installing moviepy and imageio and importing imageio without error. 
I keep getting the following error and cannot figure out the solution:

```
Imageio: 'ffmpeg-osx-v3.2.4' was not found on your computer; downloading it now.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)>.
Error while fetching file: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)>.

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-8b0dfa2efbcc> in <module>()
          3 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
          4 import imageio
    ----> 5 imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
          6 import matplotlib
          7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.pyc in download(directory, force_download)
        71     get_remote_file(fname=fname,
         72                     directory=directory,
    ---> 73                     force_download=force_download)
        74 
        75 

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imageio/core/fetching.pyc in get_remote_file(fname, directory, force_download, auto)
      125             return filename
       126     else:  # pragma: no cover
   --> 127         _fetch_file(url, filename)
       128         return filename
       129 

    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imageio/core/fetching.pyc in _fetch_file(url, file_name, print_destination)
        181         raise IOError('Unable to download %r. Perhaps there is a no internet '
        182                       'connection? If there is, please report this problem.' %
    --> 183                       os.path.basename(file_name))
        184 
        185
```

> IOError: Unable to download 'ffmpeg-osx-v3.2.4'. Perhaps there is a
>   no internet connection? If there is, please report this problem.

I tried all the solutions I could think of or/and found online, including the ones described here [ffmpeg installation on macOS for MoviePy fails with SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467234/ffmpeg-installation-on-macos-for-moviepy-fails-with-ssl-error?answertab=active#tab-top), but nothing helped.
Does anyone found another solution?

Thanks